# How do I filter the data from the database and then print the result as pdf

Tags: php

I use the data table library to display the data. It has a search field. How can I generate a pdf that prints the data in the table and not directly from the database in order to benefit from the search field?

```
<?php
require "fpdf/fpdf.php";
include "db.php";
include "patients-class.php";
$db= new Database();
$conn = $db->getConnection();
$patient_obj= new patient($conn);

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B",16);
$pdf->SetTextColor(252,3,3);
$pdf->cell(200,20,"patients information","0","1","C");
//table columns
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->Cell(15,10,"NO","1","0","C");
$pdf->Cell(30,10,"Name","1","0","C");
$pdf->Cell(55,10,"Email","1","0","C");
$pdf->Cell(30,10,"Phone ","1","0","C");
$pdf->Cell(30,10,"Birth Date","1","0","C");
$pdf->Cell(30,10,"Gander","1","1","C");


$stmt=$patient_obj->viewAllPatients();
$i=0;
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $i++;
 extract($row);
 $pdf->SetFont("Arial","",11);
$pdf->Cell(15,10,$i,"1","0","C");
$pdf->Cell(30,10,$patientFName." ".$patientLName,"1","0","C");
$pdf->Cell(55,10,$email,"1","0","C");
$pdf->Cell(30,10,$phoneNumber,"1","0","C");
$pdf->Cell(30,10,$birthDate,"1","0","C");
$pdf->Cell(30,10,$gander,"1","1","C");
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","",14);

}
$pdf->Output();
```

and this is my data table as you see the data here come from the database but the search button enables me to filter the data I want the same when I click on Pdf

```
<table id="table" class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>phone Number</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Gander</th>
                <th>action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            $stmt=$patient_obj->viewAllPatients();
            while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
             extract($row);
            echo"<tr>
                <td>{$patientFName} {$patientLName}</td>
                <td>{$birthDate}</td>
                <td>{$phoneNumber}</td>
                <td>{$address}</td>
                <td>{$gander}</td>
                <td><a href='#' title='view Details' class='text-success p-2 addappoment' appomentId='{$patientID}'> <i class='fas fa-calendar-check'></i></a>
                <a href='#' title='Edit' class='text-primary p-2 editBtn' updatedId='{$patientID}'><i class='fas fa-user-edit'></i> </a>
                <a href='#' title='Delete' class='text-danger p2 deleteBtn' deletedId='{$patientID}'><i class='fas fa-user-times'></i> </a>
                
                </td>
            </tr>
            ";
            }
            ?>
            
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: the same you do when creating any PDF file. You search the data first, get it from DB, you can choose to display it with a button to create the PDF or directly create the PDF once the data is found. its the same because you just pass the parsed HTML with data to FPDF to create the PDF file

Comment: `$stmt=$patient_obj->viewAllPatients();` instead of `allPatient` you should fetch the data based on the filter of your choosing, like, `name`, `id` or something